# In SwiftUI on MacOS Detect Clicks and Doubleclicks in List

Tags: swiftui, swift3

I have a List with a few lines.
The Lines contain two clickable Images and some text.

Clicking or Double-Clicking the Images shall trigger an action.
Clicking anywhere else in the Line shall select the Line in the List.
Double-Clicking anywhere else in the Line shall trigger an action.

The following code works in iOS, what's to be done, that it works in MacOS.

In MacOS (13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d)) I have the effect, that selection of lines with a single Click does not work properly.

```
struct Line_List: View {
  @State private var selectedRow: Int? = nil
  var body: some View {
    List(1..<11, id: \.self, selection: $selectedRow) { index in
      Line(index: index)
    }
  }
}

struct Line: View {
  var index: Int
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack (alignment: .top) {
      Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
          print("Icon 1 Double-Clicked")
        }
        .onTapGesture (count: 1){
          print("Icon 1 Single-Clicked")
        }        
      VStack (alignment: .leading){
        Text("Line: \(index)")
        Text("Some other Text")
      }
      Spacer()
      Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
          print("Icon2 Double-Clicked")
        }
        .onTapGesture (count: 1){
          print("Icon2 Single-Clicked")
        }
      
    }
    .background(Color.green)
    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {  // does not work in MacOS
      print("Line Double-Clicked")
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me on Ventura.

Comment: @Hongtron try a bit Clicking around, then the selection of lines does not work anymore, I will clarify this in the post

Comment: I see the issue now. Single clicking the line does not select unless you click right on the edge / in the black separator.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that works for me for selecting the row is to pass the selection as a binding to the Line view and add a single onTapGesture to change the selection binding to the index value. I am sure this is to do with layers of what is picking up the tapGesture. Putting both on the background color allows it to determine between single and double click.

```
struct Line: View {
  var index: Int
    @Binding var selectedRow: Int? // <- Adding a binding to the selection
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack (alignment: .top) {
      Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
          print("Icon 1 Double-Clicked")
        }
        .onTapGesture (count: 1){
          print("Icon 1 Single-Clicked")
        }
      VStack (alignment: .leading){
        Text("Line: \(index)")
        Text("Some other Text")
      }
      Spacer()
      Image(systemName: "2.circle.fill")
        .onTapGesture (count: 2){
          print("Icon2 Double-Clicked")
        }
        .onTapGesture (count: 1){
          print("Icon2 Single-Clicked")
        }
    }
    .background(Color.green)
    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {  // does not work in MacOS
        print("Line \(index.description) Double-Clicked")
    }
    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {  // <- Add This
        selectedRow = index
        print("Selected Line is \(index.description)")
    }
  }
}
```